# push notifications with param don't receive windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I've come across a very strange problem. I've implemented push notifications inside my application and it works fine, but only If I don't send a param with the push notification. My application is a Windows Phone 8 Application.

For some reason the push notifications with the param won't arrive on my phone, but without the param they do. I've tried a lot if "inputs" to check if it was because it wasn't a valid uri, string, etc, but nothing happens.

Even stranger is that the response from the Microsoft server says that it is delivered.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-DeviceConnectionStatus: Connected X-NotificationStatus: Received
>   X-SubscriptionStatus: Active X-MessageID:
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ActivityId:
>   381e48cc-7a1d-4076-979d-953a622bfc7d X-Server: DB3MPNSM009
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 06 Sep
>   2013 19:17:32 GMT Content-Length: 0

Send, but not receiving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
                   <wp:Toast>
                        <wp:Text1>Title test</wp:Text1>
                        <wp:Text2>Message test</wp:Text2>
                        <wp:Param>/Page2.xaml</wp:Param> 
                   </wp:Toast>
                </wp:Notification>
```

Send, but not receiving

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
                   <wp:Toast>
                        <wp:Text1>Title test</wp:Text1>
                        <wp:Text2>Message test</wp:Text2>
                        <wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?id=34</wp:Param> 
                   </wp:Toast>
                </wp:Notification>
```

Send and receiving

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
                   <wp:Toast>
                        <wp:Text1>Title test</wp:Text1>
                        <wp:Text2>Message test</wp:Text2>
                        <wp:Param></wp:Param> 
                   </wp:Toast>
                </wp:Notification>
```

I've have no clue any more what the problem could be. I hope someone can help me out.

Regards,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer could be in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx... I had the same issue when I was using multiple query string parameters.

I did `?something=value&somethingelse=value` (failing)
Then I noticed the `&` was encoded using `&amp;` in the example.

So when I changed it to `?something=value&amp;somethingelse=value`, the notification was successfully received.

Comment: Your answer solved my issues. Turns out that first, I was using "&" instead of "&amp;". Once I changed that, I was just sending the "Param" value. Because of that my app did not receive any extra data when the toast arrived while the app was not running on foreground. But then, I noticed there was a fourth node I could use: "NavigationUri". Param is read only if the app is running when the toast arrives. NavigationUri (re)starts the app on a specific Page